Apple's dispatch vs OpenMP to parallelize a for loop on Apple MacBook Pro with M3Pro
I am writing a program in C that takes in an array of size 2N and swaps entries whose indices differ by one bit at a specified position in the indices' binary representations.
Profiling the code, I noticed that by default it only deploys only one thread, which makes it very slow. I tried OpenMP and also Apple's Dispatch (formerly Grand Central Dispatch) to parallelize my code, but I am a bit disappointed with the results.
Is there someone more experienced with these frameworks and can help me out?
Is Metal something I should look into?
My idea for the parallelized version of my code is to iterate through all integers up to 2N-1-1, insert a zero at the specified position from the right and swap with the entry whose index is 2pos away.
The version I implemented using OpenMP looks like this:
void swapEntries(double complex* array, uint64_t N, uint64_t pos) {
    uint64_t swapDistance = 1 << pos        // 2^pos is the distance between entries to swap
    uint64_t indices = 1 << (N - 1)         // 2^(N-1) is the max integer missing a zero at pos

#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(array, indices, pos, swapDistance)
    {
        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < indices; ++i) {
            uint64_t left = (i & (~0U << pos)) << 1;    // Copy the bits left to pos and shift
                                                        // them one position to the left
            uint64_t right = (i & ~(~0U << pos));       // Copy the bits right of pos
            i = (left | right);                         // Merge the two integers (now with a
                                                        // zero at pos)

            double complex tmp = *(array + i);              // Swap the entry with the one
            *(array + i) = *(array + (i + swapDistance));   // swapDistance away
            *(array + (i + swapDistance)) = tmp;
        }
    };
}

On an instance with N=30, using Apple's clang with flag -O2 it runs nearly twice as fast as its serial version. I find this quite sobering given the fact my MacBook M3 with M3Pro has 11 cores (even if 7 of them are efficiency cores).
In a next step I tried Apple's Dispatch library using a simple loop conversion given at wikipedia and also mentioned in the docs.
void swapEntries(double complex* array, uint64_t N, uint64_t pos) {
    uint64_t swapDistance = 1 << pos        // 2^pos is the distance between entries to swap
    uint64_t indices = 1 << (N - 1)         // 2^(N-1) is the max integer missing a zero at pos

    /* Get a concurrent dispatch queue */
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

    dispatch_apply(indices, queue, ^(size_t) {
        uint64_t left = (i & (~0U << pos)) << 1;    // Copy the bits left to pos and shift them
                                                    // one position to the left
        uint64_t right = (i & ~(~0U << pos));       // Copy the bits right of pos
        i = (left | right);                         // Merge the two integers (now with a
                                                        // zero at pos)

        double complex tmp = *(array + i);              // Swap the entry with the one
        *(array + i) = *(array + (i + swapDistance));   // swapDistance away
        *(array + (i + swapDistance)) = tmp;
    });
}

Both of these functions do exactly what they are supposed to; I have unit tests to check this.
However, the Dispatch implementation is significantly worse than the serial version and I am pretty sure that this is my fault.
Can you please help me?

Whatever the threading library used, not all codes/algorithms can be efficiently parallelized. Typically, memory-bound codes (i.e. the bottleneck is the memory bus bandwidth) do not run faster even if more cores are used, and this probably the case here. Moreover I suspect you have race conditions in this code, making it not correct (have you checked the results when it runs on more than 1 thread?).

For the efficiency comparison between OpenMP and Apple Dispatch, I cannot comment, as I have no experience at all with the latter. Just, I would 100% go with OpenMP as it is widely implemented on every platform and is portable (your Dispatch version could not be compiled/linked using a non Apple compiler, while an OpenMP code can always be compiled, even if OpenMP is not available)

@PierU thanks a lot for your comment.
I had to look up what memory-bound code means. If I got to correct you mean that access time to the array makes up for the majority of time in my code and not the elementary calculations on the entries.
For this particular task, do you think I can trade computation for memory boundaries?
Or is it a better idea to parallelize the programs calling this program and leave this as a serial computation?

For the race condition you mentioned, can you provide reference where you see a potential threat? I coded some unit tests and they all worked out quite well. However, I think the maximal N used was 4.

I have no clear idea about how your code works, so maybe it's OK. But is the redefinition of i within the loop (instead of using a temporary variable) intentional? If yes, I really doubt it's safe with multiple threads...

And performance wise, you tend to write quite randomly in the array, which can potentially create what is called "false sharing".

Your code does not compile due to missing ;s after lines 2 and 3. Furthermore having a code block ({) between the omp parallel for and the actual for-loop is illegal. One could split the pragma into omp parallel in front of the { and omp for between the { and the loop. Although I would just get rid of the code block instead.

Modifying the i inside the loop is also illegal for OpenMP. See Canonical Loop Form: "[The loop index] must not be modified during the execution of the for-loop other than in incr-expr. ", where incr-expr is the ++i in your case.

As an aside, you describe Apple's Dispatch as “formerly Grand Central Dispatch” … AFAIK, Apple has not deprecated the term GCD. The Dispatch documentation says “Dispatch, also known as Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)”. “GCD” is still an accepted term.

In answer to the general performance issue, we generally address this by “striding”, doing more work per iteration. Right now, each iteration is performing a negligible amount of work. And, in GCD, especially, if you have very little work on each iteration, the modest threading overhead can outweigh any performance benefits from multi-threading. Once you start striding, (a) the performance benefit of each will greatly improve; and (b) the difference between the two will be greatly diminished.

@Rob For OpenMP at least, I would say that what is important is not the wokrload per iteration, but the workload per chunk of iterations. Here the chunk size is $2^(N-1) / nthreads", which is not too bad with N=30.

@rob, the strange left/right calculation part actually provides the guarantee that i has a 0 at the bit represented by swapDistance and i+swapDistance actually sets this bit. For i=0b1111 and pos=2, we will have left=0b11000 and right=0b11 then concatenate them to i=0b11011. As others pointed out, this should clearly be a new variable for OpenMP. I'm wondering where I comes from for GCD and what's the scope there.

@Joachim – Agreed. I was premature on declaring this as not being thread-safe (and I’ve deleted that comment), because it does not appear that i and i+swapDistance indices are ever repeated.

@Joachim – Yeah, in the OP’s GCD example, it’s not clear where i comes from and what its scope is. I expected to see something like dispatch_apply(indices, queue, ^(size_t i) {…}), with i provided as a parameter to the block. Comparing it to the OpenMP code, clearly i was intended as the index of the loop. The OP’s code doesn’t even compile for me…

@paleonix: Of course you are right regarding the missing ; after lines 2 and 3. I just missed them while editing my code for the question. By 'the code block between the omp parallel for and the actual for-loop ...', do you mean default(none) shared(array, indices, pos, swapDistance)?
If so this is due to my IDE complaining on not setting the default(none).
@paleonix & @PierU: Thanks for the hint, I introduced a local variable in the loop holding the (left | right) instead.

No, I mean that you can't have that { (starting a new code block) after the omp for. The for loop has to come directly after that pragma. GCC even errors on it when compiling with -fopenmp. You can use a code block {} to define a parallel region, but when one fuses omp parallel with omp for to omp parallel for, it will only apply to a single loop.

OpenMP’s #pragma omp parallel for will take the iterations of the for loop and they will be “divided into contiguous non-empty subsets, called chunks”. (See section 11.5.3 of the OpenMP Application Programming Interface. This is also discussed in the ninth video of the Introduction to OpenMP training series.) Chunking maximizes the amount of work on each thread and minimizes the modest overhead introduced by parallelism.
GCD does not do this for you, and each iteration of dispatch_apply will be dispatched separately. If you want to chunk the work in GCD, you have to do this yourself, striding through the indices of the for loop, and then, inside the dispatch_apply block, you would iterate through the subset of indices yourself.
The net effect is that OpenMP will group the work into the minimum number of chunks for the desired number of threads, whereas your GCD example, in the absence of striding, there are an extraordinary number of separate dispatches, with the dispatch overhead quickly offsetting any benefits offered by parallelism.

In GCD, we remedy this by “striding”, increasing the amount of work performed on each thread. Right now, each iteration of dispatch_apply (known as concurrentPerform in Swift) is performing a negligible amount of work. And, in GCD, especially, if you have very little work on each iteration, the modest threading overhead can outweigh any performance benefits from multi-threading.
For example, consider N of 30. That will result in 536 million (2N-1) dispatches in the dispatch_apply example. Yes, dispatch_apply will mitigate the thread-explosion risk (limiting the number of active threads to the number of cores on the device), but it will not “chunk” the work for you. You have to do this yourself.
For more information about striding, see the “Improving on Loop Code” section of Apple’s legacy Concurrency Programming Guide, which says:

Listing 5-3 shows how to replace a for loop with its dispatch-based equivalent. The block or function you pass to dispatch_apply or dispatch_apply_f must take an integer value indicating the current loop iteration. In this example, the code simply prints the current loop number to the console.
Listing 5-3  Replacing a for loop without striding
queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_apply(count, queue, ^(size_t i) {
    printf("%u\n", i);
});

Although the preceding example is a simplistic one, it demonstrates the basic techniques for replacing a loop using dispatch queues. And although this can be a good way to improve performance in loop-based code, you must still use this technique discerningly. Although dispatch queues have very low overhead, there are still costs to scheduling each loop iteration on a thread. Therefore, you should make sure your loop code does enough work to warrant the costs. Exactly how much work you need to do is something you have to measure using the performance tools.
A simple way to increase the amount of work in each loop iteration is to use striding. With striding, you rewrite your block code to perform more than one iteration of the original loop. You then reduce the count value you specify to the dispatch_apply function by a proportional amount. Listing 5-4 shows how you might implement striding for the loop code shown in Listing 5-3. In Listing 5-4, the block calls the printf statement the same number of times as the stride value, which in this case is 137. (The actual stride value is something you should configure based on the work being done by your code.) Because there is a remainder left over when dividing the total number of iterations by a stride value, any remaining iterations are performed inline.
Listing 5-4  Adding a stride to a dispatched for loop
int stride = 137;
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_apply(count / stride, queue, ^(size_t idx){
    size_t j = idx * stride;
    size_t j_stop = j + stride;
    do {
       printf("%u\n", (unsigned int)j++);
    } while (j < j_stop);
});

size_t i;
for (i = count - (count % stride); i < count; i++)
   printf("%u\n", (unsigned int)i);

There are some definite performance advantages to using strides. In particular, strides offer benefits when the original number of loop iterations is high, relative to the stride. Dispatching fewer blocks concurrently means that more time is spent executing the code of those blocks than dispatching them. As with any performance metric though, you may have to play with the striding value to find the most efficient value for your code.

Their example is not perfect, but it illustrates the idea.

Thank you very much for the hint. I managed to modify my code and now its performance matches that of OpenMP.
